# Golang regex: doesn't end with string

Tags: regex, go

Usually I'd use something like this: `/^(?!.*NOT_ENDING_WITH_THIS$).*$/`

However, my Golang regex engine does not support negative lookaheads because they're not `O(n)`.

I want the match to succeed if the string doesn't end in `NOT_ENDING_WITH_THIS`.

The expression I'm looking for is the inverse of this: `^(.*(NOT_ENDING_WITH_THIS))$`

Comment: just use an if else in your code, if it didn't match `^(.*(NOT_ENDING_WITH_THIS))$` then you know it is what you're looking for, there's no need to use the other expression.

Comment: @ErnestMolner This produces matches, though, and if the string ends in `NOT_ENDING_WITH_THIS` the expression can't produce any matches

Comment: For context, it's what the `esbuild` plugins use to match files, and I want a particular plugin to ignore paths with a specific file extension. I think at least that if the regex matches, the parth is processed.

Comment: Sorry, @Lucien I'm not familiar with this framework. But it should be possible to ignore cases that match the regex pattern you don't want to process using an if else

Comment: Because it's an external framework, I can't easily modify the way it works. If the regex has 1+ matches, it passes, else it fails. I'm currently going with hardcoding some values

Comment: can you pre-filter what you send to the framework?

Comment: Afraid not, it only allows providing this filter. I solved it by providing the permutations it needs